curl 77 when install aapanel on rocky linux 9.3 mnimal
when i try to install aapanel to rocky linux, i have this error, find error but cant fix it, can someone help me. 1st time move from centos to rocky linux. thank alot

Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for http://mirrors.rockylinux.org/mirrorlist?arch=x86_64&repo=BaseOS-9 [error stting certficate fie: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt]
Error: failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for http://mirrors.rockylinux.org/mirrorlist?arch=x86_64&repo=BaseOS-9 [error stting certficate fie: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt]


Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing code -- system administration and troubleshooting is outside our scope. That said -- should "stting", being "statting", perhaps? If the stat(2) syscall is failing when trying to collect metadata for the CA certificate bundle, does that file actually exist? Is it world-readable? Does it in fact contain a collection of root CA certificates, as it should?

I try other answer search but still cant, stackoverflow my last hope,
